# Reading lines in a text file by Bash Script

Tags: bash, docker

I'm going to read lines in a text file:

```
$SSH_PRIVATE_FILE="address"
```

I would like to read and evaluate the line in a way to assign a value to the already defined `SSH_PRIVATE_FILE`.

The follwing is a docker file's contents

```
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_FILE
COPY build-params build-params
RUN while IFS='' read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do\
    echo "Text read from file: $line";\
    eval `$line`;\
    done < "build-params"

RUN echo $SSH_PRIVATE_FILE
```

**UPDATED**

But it returns error: /bin/sh: 1: $SSH_PRIVATE_FILE="~/.ssh/id_rsa": not found

Comment: Looks like you forgot a `;` after the `eval $line`

Comment: Part of me wonders if including a private key in a docker image is a good idea, and another part of me is wondering why you don't just copy the key file itself into the image.

Comment: @chepner, actually i just temporarily get the key and at the end I delete it

Comment: @oliv acctualy i updated the question. However, your answer helped

Answer (score 0):

Bourne-type shells have a built-in mechanism to read the contents of a text file and evaluate each line, the `.` directive.  (GNU bash has the same functionality under the name `source`, but this is *not* part of the POSIX shell standard and some very-light-weight shells in Docker base images don’t support it.)  At a shell level, what you’ve written is equivalent to

```sh
. ./build-params
```

However, each Dockerfile RUN line runs a separate container with a separate shell with a clean shell environment, so this turns out to be a pretty bad way to set environment variables.  The Dockerfile ENV directive works better.

Furthermore, since you’re writing the Dockerfile, you have complete control over the filesystem layout inside the Dockerfile, and you don’t really need the locations of things *inside the Docker container* to be parametrizable.  In the case of things like credentials, you’d use the `docker run -v` option to inject things into the container.  If I needed a setting like this, I might make my Dockerfile say

```
ENV SSH_PRIVATE_FILE=/ssh/id_rsa
```

and then actually launch the container as

```sh
docker run -v $HOME/.ssh:/ssh ...
```

and not make this a build-time option at all.

Answer (score -1):

Just a wild guess, but I'd try putting a space before every `\` at the end of each line.